# Text arbitrarily not reading into buffer

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze philosophical and classic texts with the Watson Alchemy API, I'm having trouble with reading texts from a .txt file on my computer to a python variable.

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
import argparse
import json



def conceptual(fileName):
    path = "/Users/myname/Desktop/texts/"

    name = path + fileName

    with open(name, 'r') as myfile:
         data=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')

    if data != None:
    print(data)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--concepts', dest = 'conceptFile', required =    False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.conceptFile:
         conceptual(args.conceptFile)
    else:
         print('Use CL args.')

main()
```

The issue is that for some texts it works fine: The entire .txt file prints out onto the terminal window. For others it prints something like this(for all the files that aren't working the output is very similar to this):

```
.                       THE ENDy mountains. glowing and strong, like a
```

The end of that particular file (Zarauthstra_Nietzsche.txt) is

```
 Thus spake Zarathustra and left his cave, glowing and strong, like a
morning sun coming out of gloomy mountains.


                    THE END
```

But the rest of the file doesn't print.

I've been tinkering around with various differences, tweaking it here and there, but the only common thread to those that don't work seem to be that I downloaded them from a different website (http://philosophy.eserver.org/texts.htm not Project Gutenberg). I've tried changing the file's path, the contents, the permissions, the filenames. Any ideas?

Comment: data could never be None so not sure what you are doing with the `if data != None:` Also what is in the function?  Your indentation or logic seem off

Comment: okay, i guess there i was just being safe. That shouldn't have any affect on the output though. Also just updated indentation

Comment: Unless you somehow have a carriage return in there it should work fine, what is the name of a file that reproduces the error?

Comment: ah thank you! It was the \r character. I'll add comment answering my own question.

Comment: No worries, those carriage returns can be sneaky ;)

Comment: You could also run `dos2unix` on the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the \r characters in the file were somehow messing it up.

changed this line:`data=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')` to
`data=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')`